# How can I tell if a module is being called dynamically or statically?

Tags: cobol

How can I tell if a module is being called *dynamically* or *statically*?

Comment: You probably need to be specific about what Cobol you're asking about: platform, vendor, and version.

Comment: I'd upvote twice if I could. This problem irks me in Python, Ruby, Lua, and other dynamic languages. Luckily, people find hacks that can do this.

Comment: Why does it matter how you're called?

Answer (score 1):

If you are operating on z/OS, you can accomplish this, but it is non-trivial.

First, you must trace up the save area chain and use CSVQUERY to find out which program owns each save area.  Every other program will be a Cobol runtime module, like IGZCPAC.  Under IMS, CICS, TSO, et al, those modules might be different.  That is the easy part.

Once you know who owns all the relevant save areas, you can use the OS LOADER / BINDER / LINKER utilities to discover what artifacts are in the same modules.  This is the non-easy part.

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY way is to look at the output of the linkage editor (IEWL) or the load module itself. If the module is being called DYNAMICALLY then it will not exist in the main module, if it is being called STATICALLY then it will be seen in the load module. Calling a working storage variable, containing a program name, does not make a DYNAMIC call. This type of calling is known as IMPLICITE calling as the name of the module is implied by the contents of the working storage variable. Calling a program name literal.

Comment: Nope. You can INCLUDE a module that is dynamically called, so it will be in the loadmodule (won't be used, though). You can fail to have your statically called module in the search, so it won't be in the loadmodule (heading for a S0C1). A call to a dataname is *always* a dynamic call.

Answer (score 0):

> Calling a working storage variable,
>   containing a program name, does not
>   make a DYNAMIC call.

Yes it does. Call variablename is *always* DYNAMIC.
Call 'literal' is dynamic or static according to the DYNAM/NODYNAM compiler option.

Caveat: This applies for IBM mainframe COBOL and I believe it is also part of the standard. It may not apply to other non-standard versions of COBOL.

Answer (score 0):

For Micro Focus COBOL statically linking is controlled via [call-convention](http://documentation.microfocus.com:8080/help/index.jsp?topic=%2FGUID-0E0191D8-C39A-44D1-BA4C-D67107BAF784%2FHRCDRHCDIR46.html) on the call (bit 3) or via the compiler directive [LITLINK](http://documentation.microfocus.com:8080/help/index.jsp?topic=%2FGUID-0E0191D8-C39A-44D1-BA4C-D67107BAF784%2FHRCDRHCDIR46.html).

When linking statically the case of the program-id/entry-point and the call itself is important, so you may want to ensure it is exact and use the [CASE](http://documentation.microfocus.com:8080/help/index.jsp?topic=%2FGUID-0E0191D8-C39A-44D1-BA4C-D67107BAF784%2FHRCDRHCDIR46.html) directive.

The reverse of LITLINK directive is the NOLITLINK directive or a call-convention without bit 3 set!

On Windows you can see the exported symbols in your .dll by using the "dumpbin /exports" utility and on Unix via the 'nm' utility.

A import .lib for the .dll created via "cbllink" can be created by using the '-K'command line option on cbllink.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the *call* statement. If the called program is described in a literal then it's a static call. It's called a dynamic call if the called program is determined at runtime:

```
      *     Static call
            call "THEPROGRAM"

      *     Dynamic call
            call wsProgramName
```

Comment: No, at least not on an IBM Mainframe. Compiler option DYNAME will make `CALL "literal"` a dynamic CALL.